# Didn’t get +100 for association

Tags: support

I haven’t posted here before, but my question was migrated from SO.

I don’t think I got the automatic +100 for linking profiles.

Answer (score 4):

This is how the 100 pts for association works. To get the points, you need to associate your Meta account and your SO account [**as described on Meta Stackoverflow:**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35033/bonus-points-for-merging-accounts/35035#35035)

> The system uses your OpenID to know which accounts are eligible for
>   associating, so you need to make sure you used the same OpenID on both
>   sites. Bonus points are only given to users with accounts above a
>   certain amount of rep.

That rep amount is **200 pts**.

But the system was (is?) glitchy sometimes. So you may need to disassociate and then relink accounts if the +100 points doesn't show up, more details [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70351/did-not-get-100-reputation-for-associating-account) and how to do this. Also, remember that you need at least 200 pts of rep **at the time** you make the association in order to get the +100 pts on the other account.

Comment: Maybe I did get the points, but it didn’t show up in the history. I guess that is a separate bug.

Comment: The bonus points for associating two accounts, where one account has a reputation higher than 199, are not shown in the history; it is reported in http://se-site.com/reputation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Could you repost that link please? It sent me to a Polish language website's 404 page. Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the reputation URL that is available from any SE site (e.g. stackoverflow.com/reputation, drupal.stackexchange.com/reputation, superuser.com/reputation). I used "se-site" to mean "any SE site."

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you! I just realized that in comments, anything that looks like a URL is probably auto-converted to an active link.